# Java - Words and Phrase Frequency Counting

Tags: java, design-patterns, cpu-word, frequency, phrase

This is my dilema.

I need a function which would find the most occurring string pattern in a random text.

So if the input is this:

```
my name is john jane doe jane doe doe my name is jane doe doe my jane doe name is jane doe I go by the name of john joe jane doe is my name
```

Output sorted by occurrence should look like this (case insensitive):

```
  Rank    Freq  Phrase
      1       6  jane doe
      2       3  my name
      3       3  name is
      4       2  doe doe
      5       2  doe doe my
      6       2  doe my
      7       2  is jane
      8       2  is jane doe
      9       2  jane doe doe
     10       2  jane doe doe my
     11       2  my name is
     12       2  name is jane
     13       2  name is jane doe
etc...
```

In my case I need only phrases with 2 and more words.
Any idea how to approach this issue?

Comment: Please show us [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I've working code for counting single word occurrence, but it's unusable for matching of patterns/phrases (which could be of unlimited size). I am really just starting to think about this as we speak. I am thinking to split entire text to words, then start pairing first with next and expand selection as I go and keep counters... something of that sort.

Comment: For illustration, following online phrase counter is doing exactly what I need: http://www.writewords.org.uk/phrase_count.asp

Comment: Sounds like your thinking is on the right track, any specifics you have a question on?

Comment: You said "I am really just starting to think about this" - maybe you could do some more thinking yourself, before asking the rest of the Stack Overflow community to do your thinking for you.

Comment: you almost certainly want to solve this using regular expressions. In your example a phrase is just two words = "([[:alnum:]]\w[[:alnum:]])",  so set the regexp to "word1\w+word2" and match it against the input and then print the match count. Shift the input phrase one word to the left str2 = str1.substring( str1.indexOf("\w", length); then repeat.  '\w' is whitespace... java.util.regexp...

Comment: That sounds like a viable option, except I know a very little about regex and how would it work for counting 3, 4 or more words. Is there a regex which can account for that option?

Comment: well, if you are a student, a book on regular expressions could be *real* handy...

Comment: Thanks, in any way, first comment was really helpful. I am exploring regex now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ORIGINAL VERSION - Due to using the String concatenation operator `+`, this version is very wasteful of both CPU and memory because it creates new `char[]` objects and copies data from one to another with each use of `+`.

```
public class CountPhrases {
    public static void main(String[] arg){
        String input = "my name is john jane doe jane doe doe my name is jane doe doe my jane doe name is jane doe I go by the name of john joe jane doe is my name";

        String[] split = input.split(" ");
        Map<String, Integer> counts = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
        for(int i=0; i<split.length-1; i++){
            String phrase = split[i];
             for(int j=i+1; j<split.length; j++){
                phrase += " " + split[j];
                Integer count = counts.get(phrase);
                 if(count==null){
                     counts.put(phrase, 1);
                 } else {
                     counts.put(phrase, count+1);
                 }
             }
        }

        Map.Entry<String,Integer>[] entries = counts.entrySet().toArray(new Map.Entry[0]);
        Arrays.sort(entries, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Map.Entry<String, Integer> o1, Map.Entry<String, Integer> o2) {
                return o2.getValue().compareTo(o1.getValue());
            }
        });
        int rank=1;
        System.out.println("Rank Freq Phrase");
        for(Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry:entries){
            int count = entry.getValue();
            if(count>1){
                System.out.printf("%4d %4d %s\n", rank++, count,entry.getKey());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Rank Freq Phrase
   1    6 jane doe
   2    3 name is
   3    3 my name
   4    2 name is jane doe
   5    2 jane doe doe
   6    2 doe my
   7    2 my name is
   8    2 is jane doe
   9    2 jane doe doe my
  10    2 name is jane
  11    2 is jane
  12    2 doe doe
  13    2 doe doe my

Process finished with exit code 0
```

NEW VERSION - Using `String.substring` saves both CPU and memory, as all Strings obtained by substring share the same `char[]` under the hood.  This should run much faster.

```
public class CountPhrases {
    public static void main(String[] arg){
        String input = "my name is john jane doe jane doe doe my name is jane doe doe my jane doe name is jane doe I go by the name of john joe jane doe is my name";

        String[] split = input.split(" ");
        Map<String, Integer> counts = new HashMap<String,Integer>(split.length*(split.length-1)/2,1.0f);
        int idx0 = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<split.length-1; i++){
            int splitIpos = input.indexOf(split[i],idx0);
            int newPhraseLen = splitIpos-idx0+split[i].length();
            String phrase = input.substring(idx0, idx0+newPhraseLen);
            for(int j=i+1; j<split.length; j++){
                newPhraseLen = phrase.length()+split[j].length()+1;
                phrase=input.substring(idx0, idx0+newPhraseLen);
                Integer count = counts.get(phrase);
                if(count==null){
                     counts.put(phrase, 1);
                } else {
                     counts.put(phrase, count+1);
                }
            }
            idx0 = splitIpos+split[i].length()+1;
        }

        Map.Entry<String, Integer>[] entries = counts.entrySet().toArray(new Map.Entry[0]);
        Arrays.sort(entries, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Map.Entry<String, Integer> o1, Map.Entry<String, Integer> o2) {
                return o2.getValue().compareTo(o1.getValue());
            }
        });
        int rank=1;
        System.out.println("Rank Freq Phrase");
        for(Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry:entries){
            int count = entry.getValue();
            if(count>1){
                System.out.printf("%4d %4d %s\n", rank++, count,entry.getKey());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

OUTPUT

```
Rank Freq Phrase
   1    6 jane doe
   2    3 name is
   3    3 my name
   4    2 name is jane doe
   5    2 jane doe doe
   6    2 doe my
   7    2 my name is
   8    2 is jane doe
   9    2 jane doe doe my
  10    2 name is jane
  11    2 is jane
  12    2 doe doe
  13    2 doe doe my

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Wow wow wow. I woke up earlier to work on this and voila!, here is my code done and ready. Please tell me you live in Toronto and I'll take you out for a beer.

Comment: Nope, I'm in Texas. Just make sure you understand everything that's happening in that code. :)

Comment: It works just fine when I am running this code on about 300 words on my computer. But I've got into some major issues running this code on Android. It fails by running out of memory. Considering that I have a top of the line device (HTC One), I worry to release this as part of the code, it would most probably cause issues. Too bad, it was doing exactly what I needed.

Comment: Is there any way to adjust it to look for max. 2 or 3 words? That would probably speed it up and resolve the memory issue as well.

Comment: I'll give you a hint: you would have to adjust the j for loop.

Comment: I've tried to adjust j in the loop from j<split.length to j<3 before even posting, but it didn't bring any results.

Comment: The inner loop depends on the value of i for its lower value and depends on both i and split.length for its upper value.

Comment: Ah, I get it... so adjusting it to for(int j=i+1; j<i+2; j++) should let me control the words to length of two... correct?

Comment: basically but you also want to make sure you don't get an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception at the end.

Comment: Also, how big is the string you're parsing that you're running out of memory?

Comment: I've accounted for ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception at the end by wrapping executing in an inner loop with (j<split.length). Works nicely now. Regarding Android, it's on average about 300 words, but I think what is happening is that the CPU usage goes 100% and memory requirement starts to grow, so Android prevents the operation somehow. It's somehow related to Heap Memory allocation - my guess.

Comment: Updated to make it go faster without being constrained on max phrase length/number of words.  (Voting up comments is another good way to show appreciation. :))

Comment: Also I just updated it to initialize the hashmap to have approximately the right number of buckets and a load factor so that it won't have to rehash.

Comment: You're a pure genius. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I've just tested it and it seems to be also a lot faster now. Really good job.

Answer (score 0):

Use the idea of the [Markov Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_algorithm) of counting the words neighbors to create relations between words. Initially goes with one word, next with two and so on.

Comment: Any code example suitable for my needs?

Answer (score 0):

```
    String txt = "my name is songxiao name is";
    List<Map<String, Integer>> words = new ArrayList<Map<String, Integer>>();
    Map map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    String[] tmp = txt.split(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i < tmp.length - 1; i++) {
        String key = tmp[i];
        for (int j = 1; j < tmp.length - i; j++) {
            key += " " + tmp[i + j];
            if (map.containsKey(key)) {
                map.put(key, Integer.parseInt(map.get(key).toString()) + 1);
            } else {
                map.put(key, 1);
            }
        }
    }
    Iterator<String> it = map.keySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        String key = it.next().toString();
        System.out.println(key + "     " + map.get(key));
    }
```

you can paste the code to you main method ,and run it .

Comment: I think it's more complex than that...